# struts 2 application uploading a file and viewing it

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am building an application using Struts 2. I have this part there in which i give the user an option to upload any pdf file that they want to. This is getting stored in a folder that i have created in my G drive. Now i want to add an option where the user can view the list of files that are present in the directory and also view or delete it.
I have already added a jsp which helps view the list.

```
package net.admin.module;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport{

    private File fileUpload;
    private String fileUploadContentType;
    private String fileUploadFileName;
    private String destPath;

    public String getFileUploadContentType() {
        return fileUploadContentType;
    }

    public void setFileUploadContentType(String fileUploadContentType) {
        this.fileUploadContentType = fileUploadContentType;
    }

    public String getFileUploadFileName() {
        return fileUploadFileName;
    }

    public void setFileUploadFileName(String fileUploadFileName) {
        this.fileUploadFileName = fileUploadFileName;
    }

    public File getFileUpload() {
        return fileUpload;
    }

    public void setFileUpload(File fileUpload) {
        this.fileUpload = fileUpload;
    }

    public String execute() 
    {
    String targetPath = "G:/FileUploadAction/";
    File fileToCreate = new File(targetPath, fileUploadFileName);
            try
            {
                    FileUtils.copyFile(this.fileUpload, fileToCreate);
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                    addActionError(e.getMessage());
            }
            return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String display() {
        return NONE;
    }

}
```

This is my action class

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*,java.io.*,java.util.*" errorPage="" %> 
<%! 
public static List recurseDir(String dir) { 
      String result, _result[]; 

      result = recurseInDirFrom(dir); 
      _result = result.split("\\|"); 
      return Arrays.asList(_result); 
} 

  private static String recurseInDirFrom(String dirItem) { 
    File file; 
    String list[], result; 

    result = dirItem; 

    file = new File(dirItem); 
    if (file.isDirectory()) { 
      list = file.list(); 
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
        result = result + "|"  + recurseInDirFrom(dirItem + File.separatorChar + list[i]); 
      } 
    return result; 
  } 
%> 
<% 
String path = "G:/FileUploadAction/";  
     List sd=recurseDir(path); 
     for(int i=0;i<sd.size();i++) 
     { 
          out.println(i+"  "+sd.get(i)+"<br>"); 
      } 
%>
<%
File f=new File("G:/FileUploadAction/Holiday List.pdf");

f.delete();

%>
```

This is my jsp which lists the files already present.

How can i go on to view it and delete it ?

Comment: Is this some exercise? I see a couple of similar question posted today. Please tag it as such. You can fetch a list of filenames. Create a table to display the files. On clicking the filename open the file and on checkboxselect and delete, invoke another action or another method in the same action to delete the file and return message whether file delete was successful.

Comment: And a suggestion, java could should go into the java classes to the extent possible instead of JSPs.